# UPDATE statement not working in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm using the following command to update a field in my database:

```
UPDATE Movies SET 'From'=2 WHERE 'Name'="foo";
```

I'm using sqlite3.exe in windows (command prompt). Although no error message is produced, nothing changes in the table. I examined the database with a couple of gui tools and I'm sure UPDATE does nothing.

'From' is of type integer and 'Name' is text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you've got is that you're getting your quoting wrong. SQLite follows the SQL standard here, and that specifies what quote characters to use: `'…'` is for strings, and `"…"` is for tokens (like special names used as column or table names). Sometimes it manages to guess what you mean anyway and compensate for getting it wrong, but it can't with the `WHERE` clause because that is syntactically correct (if decidedly unhelpful):

Swapping the quoting appears to work:

```
UPDATE Movies SET "From"=2 WHERE "Name"='foo';
```

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't good column names.  Both are keywords, best avoided, and not self-explanatory at all.

Do a SELECT to see how many rows match the WHERE clause in the UPDATE.  If none come back, you have your answer.

Did you commit the UPDATE?  Is auto commit turned on?

Comment: Thank you for getting me out of absolute disappointment. I got two more question: 1) can I change a column name after creation? 2) what is that thing: 'commit'? I've never heard of it. How can I turn it on?

Comment: That's because I'm new to stackiverflow.com